# link to another section on the same page html not working, why?

Tags: html

I am trying to link the nav buttons on a basic html page. Why doesn't it work? Here is my code:

```
<!-- Primary Menu -->
        <div class="module menu left">
            <ul id="nav-primary" class="nav nav-primary">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#solution">Solution</a></li>
                <li><a href="#facilities">Facilities</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and then ..... 
For the first link:

```
<section id="home" class="fullheight dark bg-black">
```

For the 2nd link:

```
<h3 id="about"><b><center>Clean Water Innovations was formed to bring solutions for our collective need for clean water.</center></b></h3>
```

For the 3rd Link:

```
<h1 id="solution"><b>Solution:</b></h1>
```

For the 4th Link:

```
<section id="facilities">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
```

For the 5th Link:

```
<!-- Section / Contact -->
<section id="contact" class="bg-dark dark">
```

Why is this happening? It looks properly linked to me.

Comment: Works fine based on what you've shown. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9h0p1g84/

Comment: Make sure you have enough content in each section. Expand on "not working." You probably know this, but just to clarify: hashed hyperlinks jump scroll position. If there's nothing to scroll, it may appear to be "not working."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the code segment below -

```html
href="#home"
```

Try as shown below -

```html
href="index.html#home"
```

The above code segment worked pretty well for me.